# while loop does not pass to another while loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop

i have two functions with while loop, the results from the first loop is used in the second one as an until condition, but when calling the two functions in the main it execute only the first one and it doesn't even enter the second function it just give me the results of the first loop.

in the first function `self.user_association()` there is a linear optimization using PULP i though it is the one causing the problem but it was not because when calling the loop function `block_estimated_access_link()` in the second one it works just fine but my program does not work that way because as i said i use the results from the first loop in the second one. Here is the code, can someone tell me what am i doing wrong or what is the problem exactly?

```
def block_Estimation_ACCESS_LINK(self):
    while (self.iteration < self.Iter_max):
        self.User_association()
        self.estimated_access_power()
        self.calcul_alpha()
        self.calcul_rate_am()
        self.User_association()
        self.iteration += 1
def block_bg_power_allocation(self):
     EPS = 0.0000000000001
     RamTot = 0
     while (self.iteration < self.Iter_maxB):
         self.calcul_power_backhaul()
         print('backhaul Pok=', self.p_ok)
         self.calcul_delta()
         self.calcul_rok()
         for i in self.station:
            for j in self.users:
                self.Ram = numpy.delete(self.Ram, self.Ram[0])
            RamTot = sum(self.Ram)
            if EPS <= (self.Rok[i] - sum(self.Ram[i])):
                 self.iteration += 1
def main(self):
     self.block_Estimation_ACCESS_LINK()
     self.block_bg_power_allocation()
```

Comment: Can you define what "does not work" mean, in this case?

Comment: @rdas it stops in the first function and it does not execute the second function

Comment: Is there a particular reason that you're using the same attribute `self.iteration` in both `while` loops? If they run completely separately, I'd think it would make more sense to use separate (probably local) variables. The only thing I could guess that would cause your code to behave the way you describe is if `self.Iter_maxB` is less than or equal to `self.Iter_max`.

Comment: @Prune the code begins with a class  and a def __init__(self)  function and all the other functions use the object self. It is a really long code with a lot of math equations so it can not be minimize i have no error i have the results when using print it just the problem in the main it does not execute the second  function

Comment: @Blckknght self.Iter_maxB = self.Iter_max that was my way trying to see if i can solve the problem but it didn't work. So do you think that is what causing this problem?

Comment: See this lovely [debug](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) blog for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first function you're doing this:

```
self.iteration += 1
```

And then, in the second function your stop condition is:

```
while (self.iteration < self.Iter_maxB):
```

So the first function would increment `self.iteration` to `self.Iter_max`. Now, if `self.Iter_maxB` is the same value as `self.Iter_max`, your second functions loop will never execute. I suspect that's what's happening here. Check those two varaibles. 
Fix would be something like this if you want to execute both those loops the same number of time:

```
def main(self):
     self.block_Estimation_ACCESS_LINK()
     self.iteration = 0
     self.block_bg_power_allocation()
```